# Why am i getting this warning in "if (fd=fopen(fileName,"r") == NULL)"?

Tags: c, file-handling

```
FILE *fd;
if (fd=fopen(fileName,"r") == NULL)
{   
    printf("File failed to open");
    exit(1);
}
```

This is a code snippet. When I compile it with gcc, i get the following warning:-

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

When I put **fd=fopen(argv[2],"r")** within brackets, the problem gets solved..

I am not able to understand **where am i converting integer to pointer** when the brackets are not put.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Due to operator precedence rules the condition is interpreted as `fd=(fopen(fileName,"r") == NULL)`. The result of `==` is integer, `fd` is a pointer, thus the error message.

Consider the "extended" version of your code:

```
FILE *fd;
int ok;
fd = fopen(fileName, "r");
ok = fd == NULL;
// ...
```

Would you expect the last line to be interpreted as `(ok = fd) == NULL`, or `ok = (fd == NULL)`?

Comment: This answer actually explains the warning.

Answer (score 3):

The precedence of the equality operator is higher than the assignment operator. Just change your code to:

```
FILE *fd;
if ((fd=fopen(fileName,"r")) == NULL)
{   
    printf("File failed to open");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`==` has higher precedence than `=`, so it compares the result of `fopen()` to `NULL`, then assigns that to `fd`.

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis around the assignment:

```
if ((fd=fopen(fileName,"r")) == NULL)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

== has a higher priority than =.

Answer (score -1):

Have you done the following?

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Without this, the compiler assumes all functions return an `int`.

Comment: mark downs with no comments?  Bad form ppl.  Help me to learn from my error.  Also note - it was a question, not an assertion.